# if successfully insert into database, insert into another database PHP

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO nextofkin(username,password,contact,email) VALUES('$NOKUN','$NOKPW', '$NOKContact', '$NOKEmail')";


if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
  $sql = "INSERT INTO users(username,password,role) VALUES ('$NOKUN','$NOKPW', 'nextofkin')";
} else {
  $check1='fail';
}
```

when i run this php only the first sql statement is inserted.
How can i make the second sql statement run when i inserted into the first sql statement?

Comment: You have to run it... cough...`$conn->query()`...cough...

Comment: another database or another table within same database ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Darren pointed out, you're not actually executing the statement, you're just updating the value of `$sql`.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO nextofkin(username,password,contact,email) VALUES('$NOKUN','$NOKPW', '$NOKContact', '$NOKEmail')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
  $sql = "INSERT INTO users(username,password,role) VALUES ('$NOKUN','$NOKPW', 'nextofkin')";
  $conn->query($sql);
} else {
  $check1='fail';
}
```